# H2 database storage mechanism

Tags: java, database, junit, h2, in-memory-database

I have used H2 database for my junit tests and it works perfectly fine.
However, I have few questions regarding it's persistence properties:

1. What happens when I switch off my laptop? Are the tables and data lost in case of any restart? If yes, is there any restore possible?
2. Does H2 uses transaction logs to persist the data to a disk? I can see a database file created in my users directory. Can I replicate the data into another system using this file?
3. Can a persistence/storage mechanism configured with H2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the H2 [*Features*](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) page.

Brief summary regarding your questions:

- H2 can be configured to use either [in-memory](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) or disk-based persistence. Depending on your choice it will or will not survive power shutdown.
- The transaction support is `READ COMMITTED`.
- You can copy and reuse the file, I would not call this that data replication in the classical sense. But if you have two H2 databases one goes down f.ex. you can copy the file from the other and boot it up.

Check also the [*High Availability fpr H2 Database*](https://github.com/shesse/h2ha) project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing useful info Alexander. Just a thought though, I am using H2 as disk based persistence as my connection string is - jdbc:h2:file:~/<DBName>. But still it is faster. Using H2 as disk-based persistence means using it like traditional databases like MySQL or Oracle right? Then, how come it is faster even when used as disk based? Does it still use RAM for storage?

Comment: @SidharthaShankar faster than what ?

Comment: Faster than traditional disk based databases like MySQL.

Comment: @SidharthaShankar I think this is a very different question from the original one and you should post a new question.